# how can i change the state value with setState with one click

Tags: javascript, reactjs

how can i update the activeUrl value with setState ?

the state is

```
state = {
   activeUrl: ''
}
```

the function

```
const handleActiveMenu = () => {
      let splitUrl = window.location.href.split('/')
      let assignActive = splitUrl[4]
      this.setState({ activeUrl: assignActive })
}
```

the component

```
<Link
                className={`${activeUrl === '' ? classes.borderBottom : null}`}
                onClick={() => handleActiveMenu}
                to="/"
              >
                Beranda
              </Link>

              <Link
                className={`${
                  activeUrl === 'profil' ? classes.borderBottom : null
                }`}
                onClick={handleActiveMenu}
                to="/profil"
              >
                Inisiatif
              </Link>
```

when i trying to console.log, the activeUrl doesnt change , but after i click for 2 times, the value was change..

Comment: `this.setState` with new value is sufficient. Where are you trying to log state updates?

Comment: Hi! Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button). Stack Snippets support React, including JSX; [here's how to do one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/). On first glance, that code is okay, though it's hard to tell what's where (for instance, where do you create that handler function?).

Comment: What do you see if you log `splitUrl`?

Answer (score -1):

As far as I see, a onclick on a Link (if that is the Link from react-router-dom) may not be working. Try out a log.console or debugging if the handleActiveMenu is reached.

Additional to that, when I interpret your code correctly, you want to set the active URL after clicking the link -> You should not do that within a onClick in the Link component, try to do that within the component you called e.g. in the componentDidMount event.